# Homomorphic Encryption Notation Question

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

What does the following notation mean in a homomorphic encryption scheme?

```
ENC(x;r)
```

What does `x` and `r` refer to?

Comment: was closed as 'unclear what you're asking'. Might not be a 'difficult' question, but its very clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElGamal Homomorphic Encryption Formula Question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13223/elgamal-homomorphic-encryption-formula-question)

Comment: The question is both unclear, and a duplicate of the clearer [ElGamal Homomorphic Encryption Formula Question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/13223/555)

Answer (score 2):

x is the [plaintext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaintext) and r is the [randomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption).

Comment: ENC (X;r) in (G, q, g) is (g^r, h^r . g^m). Is my interpretation right?

Comment: No, since it uses X instead of m. $\;$

Comment: ENC (X;r) in (G, q, g) is (g^r, h^r . g^X). How about now? Just want to get it right. Thanks.

Comment: That would be additive [ElGamal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption). $\:$ Two other possibilities are multiplicative ElGamal and [Cramer-Shoup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer-Shoup). $\;\;\;$