# ElGamal Homomorphic Encryption Formula Question

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, elgamal-encryption

With Public Key $(G, q, g, h)$ where $G$ is a group, $q$ prime, $g$ a generator of $G$, Am I right in thinking that: 
$$\mathrm{Enc}(m;r) := (g^r, h^r \cdot g^m)$$

Comment: I guess you mean $ENC(m;r):=(g^r,g^m\cdot h^r)$. What you refer to is exponential ElGamal and, yes, this notation is often used to indicate which randomness is used by the encryption algorithm if the encryption is probabilistic.

Comment: Please do not open multiple nearly identical questions! This one is quite identical to [this one](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13221/homomorphic-encryption-notation-question) asked just a few minutes earlier.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [Homomorphic Encryption Notation Question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13221/homomorphic-encryption-notation-question). The later has no mention of ElGamal ! If we must keep a single question, it must be the present one (which is interesting, and would be more if it was also asked how and in what applications exponential ElGamal works; its decryption is nontrivial).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: as pointed by DrLecter in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13223#comment28497_13223)¹, the question's formula is for *exponential* ElGamal encryption, with per-encryption random $r$ explicit.

---

I'll first describe (straight) ElGamal encryption. It works in an arbitrary finite cyclic group of generator $g$ and order $q$ (with the internal law noted multiplicatively). That is, $q$ is the smallest strictly positive integer with $g^q=1$, where $1$ is the neutral in the group (the integer $1$ when working in a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_p^*$, or the point at infinity for an Elliptic Curve group). Private key is an integer $x$ in $[0,q)$. Public key can² be $h=g^{q-x}$.

Encryption of a message supposes that it was mapped to an element $\widetilde m$ *in the group* by some encoding technique. Encryption draws a random integer $r$ in $[0,q)$, and outputs the ciphertext consisting of two group elements per the formula (different from that in the question):
$$\mathrm{Enc}(\widetilde m,r)\gets(g^r,h^r\cdot\widetilde m)$$

(Straight) ElGamal decryption of ciphertext $(c_1,c_2)$ produced as above obtains $\widetilde m$ as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Dec}(c_1,c_2)&\gets {c_1}^x\cdot c_2\\
&\;={\left(g^r\right)}^x\cdot h^r\cdot\widetilde m\\
&\;=(g^r)^x\cdot (g^{q-x})^r \cdot\widetilde m\\
&\;=g^{rx+(q-x)r}\cdot\widetilde m\\
&\;=g^{qr}\cdot\widetilde m\\
&\;=(g^q)^r\cdot\widetilde m\\
&\;=1^r\cdot\widetilde m\\
&\;=\widetilde m\\
\end{align}$$
(Straight) ElGamal encryption is *multiplicatively* homomorphic (for multiplication of plaintext as mapped in the group), per the easily established relation
$$\mathrm{Enc}(\widetilde m,r)=(c_1,c_2)\quad\mathrm{Enc}(\widetilde m',r')=(c'_1,c'_2)\implies\mathrm{Dec}(c_1\cdot c'_1,c_2\cdot c'_2)=\widetilde m\cdot\widetilde m'$$
There are functional issues with (straight) ElGamal encryption:

- It is non-trivial to map and unmap an applicative message $m$ to and from an element $\widetilde m$ of the group. In $\Bbb Z_p^*$ with $q$ prime or in an ECC group, practical methods are iterative. When working in $\Bbb Z_p^*$ with $p$ prime and $q=p-1$ (implying $q$ is not prime for sizable $p$), we can take $\widetilde m=m$ but then ElGamal encryption leaks one bit³ of information about $m$.
- Multiplicative homomorphism is less useful than additive homomorphism, and not directly useful since the multiplication is on mapped messages $\widetilde m$, rather than on arbitrary messages.

---

Here *exponential* ElGamal encryption comes to the rescue, solving both problems, at the expense of making decryption hard. Its encryption takes plaintext $m$ in $\Bbb Z_q$, maps it to $\widetilde m=g^m$, then encrypts per straight ElGamal. The encryption formula becomes as in the question:
$$\mathrm{Enc}(m,r)\gets(g^r,h^r\cdot g^m)$$
Exponential ElGamal decryption decrypts per straight ElGamal yielding $\widetilde m$, then either verifies an externally supplied guess $w$ of the plaintext by checking if it holds $g^w=\widetilde m$, or solves that discrete logarithm problem yielding $w=m$.

Exponential ElGamal encryption is additively homomorphic (for addition of plaintexts modulo $q$) by composing ciphertexts as in straight ElGamal encryption.

Note: while getting $m$ in exponential ElGamal decryption requires solving a discrete logarithm problem, that's still possible for moderately large $m$, including deterministically by using [baby step/giant step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step), which has cost $\mathcal O(\sqrt m)$ group operations. Also, when in a sugroup of $\Bbb Z_p^*$, sizable speedups are possible because the discrete logarithm for base $2$ is easier: we use $g=2$, or modify encryption to $\mathrm{Enc}(m,r)\gets(g^r\bmod p,h^r\cdot2^m\bmod p)$ with $2$ of the same (prime) order $q$ as $g$.

---

¹ That was minutes after the question was posed and years before this answer.

² Sometime the public key is given as $h=g^{-x}$, which is equivalent, or as $h=g^x$, in which case $x$ should be changed to $q-x$ or equivalently $-x$ for decryption.

³ The Legendre symbol $\bigl(\frac mp\bigr)$ can be found from the ciphertext. This issue was not highlighted in the original description: Taher ElGamal's [*A Public Key Cryptosystem and a Signature Scheme Based on Discrete Logarithms*](https://caislab.kaist.ac.kr/lecture/2010/spring/cs548/basic/B02.pdf) (July 1985 in [IEEE Transactions on Information Theory](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1985.1057074), formerly in [proceedings of Crypto 1984](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-39568-7_2)).

Comment: What is "moderately large m" in terms of bits?

Comment: @Fiono: depends on how much time one is willing to spend, with what hardware, on the group, and optimizations. The order of magnitude is governed by $\mathcal O(\sqrt m)$ time and RAM, thus doubling for two extra bits in $m$. With a single thread of a modern PC, definitely $m$ of >48 bits in bearable time.

Comment: Can "baby step/giant step" or "Pollard's rho" algorithms be used to solve $mG$ in a curve like 25519, for an $m$ of 32 bits? Or you need to bruce-force it?

Comment: @Fiono: yes, baby step/giant step is fine an requires in the order of $2^{17}$ point additions, which is very feasible (sub-second I guess)